I am having a problem with signalR error: handshake was canceled
I was new to learning some video fundamental on how to manage Realtime information. I did exactly what the do but I getting {"error":"Handshake was canceled."}. I don't know what to do is the fisrt  time I use websocket enter image description here
I have try to update my signalR to the latetest version and rebuild my application but still receive the same error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What is the video address? It maybe outdated.

You need to add a message delimiter at the end of message which is acutally 0x1E in ASCII.
This charactor cannot display here. But you could get it by open a notepad. Enable Numeric Keypad. Hold Alt and input 0 0 3 0. https://altcodeunicode.com/how-to-use-alt-codes/ .Then copy this special charactor to the end of the message in postman.
When SignalR uses WebSockets or other streaming transport protocols, it sends multiple messages over the same connection. Since these are streamed, there’s no natural boundary like you would have with HTTP where each request and response is separate. Therefore, SignalR needs a way to mark the end of one message and the start of the next.
After sending this message, you will get a response that the protocol was accepted, and you will begin to receive the heartbeat (type:6) messages from the hub.

